# User littering old questions with link to website

Tags: discussion, spam, users, abuse

User [jaimeiniesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580095/jaimeiniesta) has been posting links to his website on practically anything related to [w3c-validation](/questions/tagged/w3c-validation).  Some of them aren't even answering the question (ie [How to setup W3C Unicorn validator for local URIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703486/how-to-setup-w3c-unicorn-validator-for-local-uris/11488254#11488254)), just posting the site as a way of performing w3c validation.

To me, it looks like he's attempting to use Stack Overflow's high search engine ranking to boost his own ranking.  Should I flag all the answers, or just the obvious ones?

Comment: I called a mod in, as well as warning the user via a comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447403/is-there-an-offline-w3c-validator-tool/11488181#comment15174185_11488181

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been taken care of. The proper way to handle this is to flag the answer with the flag reason of 'other', and explain why you're flagging. In this case, it would be some form of astro-turfing.

You really only need to flag one answer. As long as you explain in that answer that the user is doing this repeatedly, we'll comb through the answers.  This generally works as astro-turfers normally don't get more than 10 answers in before they're caught.. If they have, well... then it'd be nice to have the individual answers flagged.

Comment: Ah, was not familiar with the term astro-turfing (at least, as it related to this =))